# facebook page feed image is getting broken

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im using a script that gets the social network feeds of a page, but in the facebook page im getting broken images, it shows the info, but not the photo.

Facebook functiion that generates the feed data (class: socialparser):

```
/** FACEBOOK PARSE **/
    public function facebook($id,$num){
        $loader = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num='.$num.'&q=';
        $UriEncoded = $this->encodeURIComponent('https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id='.$id.'&format=rss20');
        $url = $loader.$UriEncoded;
        $response = $this->curl_call($url);
        $entries = $response['responseData']['feed']['entries'];
        $posts = array();
        foreach($entries as $post){                     
            array_push($posts,$post);           
        }
        return $posts;
    }
```

calling the feed:

```
$socialparser = new Socialparser();
$facebook_posts = $socialparser->facebook('81221197163',5);

<h2>Facebook</h2>
        <ul>
            <? foreach($facebook_posts as $fb){ ?>
                <li>
                    <p><? echo $fb['title'] ?></p>
                    <p><? echo $fb['content'] ?></p>
                </li>
                <hr>
            <? } ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Can you view the source HTML of the feed data? Are the image paths to https ?

Comment: The page post RSS feeds have been removed by Facebook a while ago - so reading the data from `https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=page_id&format=rss20` should not even work any more.